# How to stay safe on Ubuntu

Tags: security, browser, malware

I am a complete noob to linux. And I have installed ubuntu on my laptop.

My concern is Security. A lot of sources online say I don't need any anivirus software, can someone explain why this is? I relaise people dont make as much linux malware but is this enough of a reason?

If I should get something what should I get?

Also is it worth to get a sandboxed browser or a fully fledged VM for surfing (this can include going)

Finally should I uninstall windows 7 (dual booting via partition) and no longer use it (is it a sfatey concern?) I was only going to keep it for emergencies

Comment: You don't need anything. Browsers are sandboxed. Everything else is crap.

Answer (score 1):

The best security is the person using the computer. Use some of the addons mentioned, be careful which sites you visit and download from, do not click on links unless you know them.  The best anti-virus/malware will not protect you from yourself or from stupid people who leave all your information on an open database.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove windows 7 or using it offline. Ubuntu don't need antivirus software because the Linux structure is secure and softwares are packaged and hosted on Ubuntu repositories (servers). You can steel install ClamAV (command line) and ClamTk (graphical).

You can also install addons on your web browser (uBlock origin, Ghostery, HTTPS everywhere) and in thunderbird (Enigmail) to stay secure online.

Comment: Would you say a VM is worth it for browsers?

Comment: VM won't add any security.

Comment: With regards to the windows. What if I do a fresh install of it and only ever use it for remote desktoping into work? Im gonna try and get linux working but this is a backup. What are the risks with this approach?